# Gedit file browser shortcuts?

Tags: linux, gedit

What shortcuts do you use for file navigation in Gedit? Does anyone use the file browser?

I thought that these shortcuts would exist, but I can't find anything about them:

- switch focus to/from the file browser.
- disclose folder contents. (Most applications use up/down arrows for moving up and down, and the right/left arrows to open/disclose the folders.)

Do these exist?

Thanks,
Loren

Comment: Nobody seem to care about that except you and me... x3 +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume at this point that no one knows of these. (The only semi-useful shortcut I have found is F9, which simply shows/hides the file browser.)

Even the official shortcut list doesn't show anything regarding these two features:
http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/KeyboardShortcuts

For now, I'll submit this as a bug. Please let me know if this changes, so I can inform the dev team.

Loren

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts for the embedded file browser are pretty much the same as the file manager ones:
    <kbd>Enter</kbd> - open directory
    <kbd>Backspace</kbd> - go back
    <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd> - go up one level
    <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> arrows - navigate directory contents

As to how to switch focus to/from the file browser, I have added an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43145).